# In javascript how to find the height and width

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, asp.net-2.0

i am having a .aspx and masterpage page. in masterpage i am loading aspx page . in aspx page design i am using generating table structure using code-behind server in javascript how to find the height and width .

Regards,
kumar

Comment: Please be more specific. The height and width of what? (a control? a div? or do you actually mean a HTML table?)

Comment: In table i am using div at runtime i need offsetHeight .and the page is in the masterpager contentplaceholder

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the table height and width, then this should do it

var tbl = document.getElementById('tblDemo');
alert(tbl.offsetWidth + '\n' + tbl.offsetHeight);